# Coins sent - visualise shows coins moved on - so I didn't send to another wallet of mine?

Tags: traceability

Transaction ID:
6a1d9ab775f6b028a037deef37723fbf506947103f2c2f6e9c32149e0dffca34

I sent bitcoins in the above transaction.  I'm trying to determine if I sent to another wallet of mine, or to another person.

If I sent it to another wallet of mine, they would still be there, as I haven't spent them.

When I go to:
https://blockchain.info/tree/267511038

I see that the bitcoins have moved on to 
1Lw536Fvjg6KkCeAYetn7wopF3XEWbrY9y
and
32Vh3B83zoaRUsTahWTxpmcgnNXG727u7n

I'm concluding that I didn't send the coins to another wallet, but to another person, who has spent them.

amiright?

Answer (score 1):

The transaction you posted has one output of 0.06193935 BTC to [1L6RYKMx4neDxVngWtsw59EteCxDfvADBk](https://blockchain.info/de/address/1L6RYKMx4neDxVngWtsw59EteCxDfvADBk). The last time somebody spend an output from this address was today.

Based on what you describe, it's probably not your address.

Comment: Thanks for response.

How did you determine that the output from this address was today?

Comment: @raymm simply by looking at blockchain.info for the corresponding address (the link in my answer). If you scroll down, you can see all movement